# JNIUS-PYTHON3 is not defined error when debugging buildozer android

Tags: android, kivy, cython, buildozer, pyjnius

I have a Kivy app I am trying to package into an android app using Buildozer. I have installed Pyjnius and Cython but I still get a JNIUS_PYTHON3 is not defined error when it unpacks Cython in the `buildozer -v android debug` command. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error. In the folder
.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pyjnius-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/pyjnius/jnius

I created a config.pxi file which contained the following lines

```
DEF JNIUS_PLATFORM = 'android'
DEF JNIUS_PYTHON3 = 'true'
```

This got me past the error message you mentioned, although I am still stuck on further errors.

Answer (score 0):

Having now gotten my app to compile to an APK file using Buildozer, I feel that my previous answer was just masking an underlying issue of some dependencies not being correctly installed. Going back through my BASH history, the steps I followed can be summarised as...

The initial setup

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git
cd buildozer
sudo python setup.py install
```

Then create a folder within the main buildozer folder to keep the python and kivy files associated with my app

```
mkdir MyAndroidApp
cd MyAndroidApp/
cp __My_Source_Files__ ./
buildozer init
nano buildozer.spec # Edit some basic settings here
buildozer android debug deploy
```

When that build process failed, I went through a series of steps to check various dependencies. Some of the following steps appear to me to do basically the same thing, so they are probably not all required, but this is a full list of the various things I tried along the path to eventual success.

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev 
sudo apt install python3-setuptools
sudo apt install libssl-dev 
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt install python-pip

pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv
pip3 install --user --upgrade pyjnius
pip3 install --user --upgrade setuptools
pip install Cython
pip3 install setuptools
```

I was then able to use the following commands to get a successful build

```
buildozer android clean
buildozer android debug deploy
```

If you are seeing that error, then I think the correct place to start is to look at the dependencies that are being complained about in the various error messages and double check that everything is installed correctly.

In the end, it worked for me, and I hope that these notes prove some use to you in sorting through your issues as well. Good luck.

Comment: Not working. Still seeing the same error mentioned in the title of the post